# Looking for a MySQL query command to insert all the queries in local .sql file to the MySQL database on a remote server

Tags: insert, mysql

Is there a MySQL query command to upload/insert all the queries in a .sql file (generated from mysqldump) on a local server to a mysql database on a remote server?

I'd like to try and do this all within MySQL queries from within an application and avoid issuing command-line mysql commands because I think that there would be a bit more overhead in parsing the output in that way.

I'm looking for something like, e.g. in Perl:

```
my $hostname = "remote_server_address";
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:dbname:$hostname";
my $user = "user";
my $password = "password";
my $dbh= DBI->connect($remote)dsn, $user, $pw) );
my $myquery = "SPECIAL_INSERT_QUERYCOMMAND my_local_mysql_query_file.sql";
my $execute = $dbh->prepare($myquery);
$execute->execute;
```

**Update:** Additional requirements: Is there any "flow-control and resilience" whereby any connection issues between the local and remote server are handled so that the entire set of queries get transfered. And would there be a limit to the size of the file to be transferred? (I hope not).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you couldn't use the command line tool [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html)

```
cat my_local_mysql_query_file.sql | mysql -uuser -ppassword dbname
```

or on windows

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword dbname < my_local_mysql_query_file.sql
```

Comment: +1 @bpgergo Thanks I'll try this as I originally had considered. My concern is parsing any error output. Whereas if done in MYSQL completely as a query, any resultant error code returned by execute is easier to deal with. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: While using the `mysql` command line tool, all the errors will be written on the standard err (I guess). Nonetheless, that is for sure, there is a command line option [force](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_force) which will tell mysql not to stop on an error but continue. On the other hand, if you want to implement custom error handling then you'll need to write a script that parses the .sql file and runs the statements.